# Neo4j - Create relationships from JSON list

Tags: json, graph, neo4j, cypher

I'm learning how to use **Neo4j** and I'm building a quite big social network using some data that I have in a **JSON** file.

The file structure looks like this:

```
{
    "users": [
                {"id":"1", "name":"Bob", friends: ["2","3"]},
                {"id":"2", "name":"Alice", friends: ["1"]},
                {"id":"3", "name":"Robert", friends: ["1","4","5"]},
                ...
    ]    
}
```

Following [this guide](http://www.markhneedham.com/blog/2015/07/23/neo4j-loading-json-documents-with-cypher/) I managed to create all the nodes with the following **Cypher** query:

```
WITH {json} AS data
UNWIND data.users AS user
MERGE (u:User {user_id: user.id, name: user.name})
```

But now I'm stuck I'm not quite sure how to create the relationships between nodes as defined in the `friends` field. Should I `UNWIND` the `friends` field too? Should I somehow iterate over every node that I created and add a relationship with its friends? Maybe this is a basic question, but I'm just starting out with Cypher.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you should `UNWIND` the `friends` column too. You could pass through the same set of data a second time, find the users and their friends by `id` and then hook them up.

Something like this would work

```
WITH {json} AS data
UNWIND data.users AS user

// for each collection of friends
UNWIND user.friends as friend

// find the current user and their friends
MATCH (u:User {user_id: user.id}), (f:User {user_id: friend})
MERGE (u)-[:FRIENDS]-(f)
```

Better still find the user only once rather than for every friend and then match each friend in a separate clause and hook them up.

```
WITH {json} AS data
UNWIND data.users AS user

// first create/find the user in the graph
MATCH (u:User {user_id: user.id})
WITH user, u

// iterate through each collection of friends
UNWIND user.friends as friend

// find each friend
MATCH (f:User {user_id: friend})

// hook them up
MERGE (u)-[:FRIENDS]-(f)
```

or you could do it in one pass of the list...

```
WITH {json} AS data
UNWIND data.users AS user

// first create/find the user in the graph
MERGE (u:User {user_id: user.id})
ON CREATE SET u.name = user.name
WITH u, user

// iterate through each collection of friends
UNWIND user.friends as friend

// find/create stub for each of the friends
MERGE (f:User {user_id: friend})

// hookup friends
MERGE (u)-[:FRIENDS]-(f)
```

Comment: I tried your second solution and I had to add `user` to the `WITH` statement in order to compile. Anyway, it doesn't create any node.

Comment: good catch - i updated query 2 and 3 to reflect the addition of user to the `WITH` clause.  The second query was meant to be run after your first query that created the nodes.  The 3rd query was meant to create the nodes and the relationships in one pass.

Comment: Sorry, I misunderstood. My query + your 2nd query work, while the 3rd one seems to hang and never complete. (If you are familiar with the Java driver for Neo4j, it seems that it never closes the `Transaction`). I'm testing these queries with a sample file of 100 rows, but my actual JSON file contains almost a million rows, so I don't know if any of these approaches will be feasible. I didn't realize they were so heavy.

Comment: I was able to just assign `:param json` in the browser and run the third query in the browser (3.1.3 community). I created 1mm rows of my own, each with 3 random friends, and wrote some groovy to load it. I can consistently load the 1mm rows and 3 friends in ~5-6 mins. Re:transaction not closing: are you using `tx.success(); tx.close();`?

Comment: Yes, I was using those. Anyway, If I can run it in the browser, I'll try there. Where should I assign the parameter? Also, do you know if converting the JSON to CSV would improve performance?

Comment: Definitely, simply using `LOAD CSV` in the cypher-shell or even the browser would be faster than this approach. Ensure you add an index or constraint on :User(user_id) before you load.


To set params in the browser... `:param json: <value here>`.

Comment: might want to take a look at this too as a possibility... https://neo4j-contrib.github.io/neo4j-apoc-procedures/#_loading_data_from_web_apis_json_xml_csv ... I have not tried it but somebody told me it was cool :)

Comment: If you are looking for real speed though you can build a database from scratch using `neo4j-admin import`. This would be very fast for 1mm rows but you need to reformat your data and it builds the database files directly.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. I ended up converting my JSON file to CSV and using my query and your second query. I also used `PERIODIC COMMIT` and the constraint. Plenty of guides online for CSV importing, anyway.

Comment: np... one thing you could do with your query if you wanted to squeeze out a few more seconds is use `CREATE` instead of `MERGE`. And then add your index/constraint after your query loads.

Comment: It says Neo.ClientError.Statement.ParameterMissing: Expected parameter(s) for all 3 solutions.